# Mountain Lion PKG signing

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, pkg-file

I have a plug-in which according to the guidelines need not be signed but I also have pkg installer(which installs the plug-in) which has to be signed. So I signed both my plug-in and pkg file, to be on the safer side. Since there is no check for plug-ins I haven't seen any issues. But I have issues with my pkg installer. I signed by pkg installer on 10.6.8 so that I can reuse it on 10.5, 10.6, 10.7 and 10.8. I used the following command

```
productsign --sign "Developer ID Installer: My Company" /Volumes/code/MyInstaller.pkg "/Volumes/code/My Installer.pkg"
```

The logs displayed by productsign was encouraging

```
productsign: signing product with identity "Developer ID Installer: My Company" from keychain /Users/vishveshk/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
productsign: adding intermediate certificate "Developer ID Certification Authority"
productsign: Wrote signed product archive to /Volumes/code/My Installer.pkg
```

When I checked it on 10.8 using

```
sudo spctl -a -v My Installer.pkg
```

The result was bad

```
My Installer.pkg: rejected
source=no usable signature
```

I signed my plug-in on the same machine and it seems to be working fine. Am I doing anything wrong? Any insights on this will be useful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. The issue is that your spctl command line is wrong. According to [Apple's documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html), you need to specify the type, like so:

spctl -a -v **--type install** MyPackageName.pkg

Chances are that your signed package works fine under Mountain Lion. It was just the problematic command line that misled you into thinking that there was a signature problem.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to figure it out.